# Difference between vito and caveo

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

I was reading *De Imitatione Christi* to get more familiar with the structure of a text in Latin and I notice that the author usually uses the verb *caveo* whenever referring to 'avoid' or 'beware' (such as in: *De cavenda nimia familiaritate*). Maybe because of my mother tongue, but first thing that comes to my mind isn't *caveo*, but *vito*. Are these verbs equivalent in usage?

I can read and understand much better than I can write or formulate sentences. Does a sentence like: "*Hi a timentibus Dei vitandum.*" make sense in Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are related, but they are not equivalent.

*Vitare* means 'to shun/to avoid' and has a sense of moving or staying away from something. A better synonym for it would actually be *fugere* 'to flee.'

*Cavere* can be used in that way, but that's a more developed metaphor. Instead, it more means 'to beware of' in the sense of 'to be on your guard against.' If you see a signing warning you *cave canem*, they do not necessarily mean for you to run away from the house (or maybe they do!), but to be on your guard that there is a dog. If they chose *vita canem* instead, it would indicate that you should avoid the dog altogether, not just be careful because they have one.

What *cavere* connotes that *vitare* does not necessarily is to be on your guard. *Vita praedones* would have you flee from bandits, but *cave praedones* just alerts you to be on guard; choosing whether to fight or flee is not part of the command.

Comment: @cmwm thank you, that was very clarifying! But what about the sentence I wrote? Is it a right construction in latin?

Comment: @YetAnotherUsr No, it does not appear to be grammatical. What are you trying to say with it in English?